# Get value of description from another website

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a PHP script that would grab data from another website and store in a database (to then graph the data).

The data that I'm trying to grab is in the description tag of the source code:

```
<meta name="description" content="123" />
```

What I need is to grab the value in `content` every hour or so.

How would I do this?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yeah, just found my own answer using `get_meta_tags()`.

Comment: great, you can answer you own question here also

Comment: There, I answered it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply using the `get_meta_tags()` method:

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.website.com');

echo $tags['description'];
```

Comment: When you can, remember to accept this answer by clicking on the large green tick mark under the question's score :)